# sender doesnt recieve mail in popup contact form in php

Tags: php, email

I m trying pop up contact form in php. Popup form works fine.But i want the mail received by both sender and recipient. In my form recipient receives the mail whereas the sender doesn't receive the mail. Can you please help me whats wrong in the code. Here is the code

```
  <form id='contactus' action='javascript:fg_submit_form()' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
    <input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />
    <div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
    <div id='fg_server_errors' class='error'></div>
    <div class='container'>
        <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='' maxlength="50" /><br/>
        <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
        <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='' maxlength="50" /><br/>
        <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
        <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
        <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'></textarea>
    </div>

<?php

require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
require_once("./include/captcha-creator.php");
$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$captcha = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');
$formproc->EnableCaptcha($captcha);

//1.Add your email address here.
//You can add more than one receipients.
$formproc->AddRecipient('abc@gmail.com'). $email;



$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('dz0sbNoc7mZPgXa');

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    if($formproc->ProcessForm())
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$formproc->AddRecipient('senderEmail@gmail.com, receiverEmail@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Sender email must be the person who enters the mail in the form.whatever email the person enters in the form they should receive the mail

Comment: Then Make those fields dyanamic like $receiverEmail=$_POST['email'];  and $formproc->AddRecipient($senderEmail, $receiverEmail);

Comment: now sender is getting mail but receiver is not getting mail. recievermail id should be abc@gmail.com

Comment: I think that function doesn't take array. Can you try this  $formproc->AddRecipient($senderEmail);
$formproc->AddRecipient($receiverEmail);

Answer (score 0):

```
$formproc->AddRecipient('abc@gmail.com'). $email;
```

This line looks really questionable. What are you trying to do here. If you want to send to two users you need to make two calls to the `AddRecipient` method

Comment: I need to send the mail to the sender and recipent as well

Comment: Which is why I said you need two calls, one for the sender and one for the recipient.